# Expression pattern of type Int cannot match values of type (int) -> Int

Tags: ios, swift

The below code is giving an error for each value next to "Case" "Expression pattern of type Int cannot match values of type (int) -> Int". I am not really sure how to give this. I am thinking I have to change the Int to another type. I tried some option but no luck clearing the error.  The value being passed to the variable comparison rate is a double value.

```
     var comparisonRate: Double = 0
        switch IRDComparisonTerm {
        case 12:
            comparisonRate =  oneYear

        case 24:
            comparisonRate =  twoYear
        case 36:
            comparisonRate =  threeYear
        case 48:
            comparisonRate = fourYear
        case 60:
            comparisonRate = fiveYear

        default:
            comparisonRate = 0

        }
```

Comment: Maybe the IRDComparionTerm is an optional? Try using IRDComparisonTerm! instead.

Comment: @Pochi Your first reaction to handling and Optional should **not** be force unwrapping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error suggests, `IRDComparisonTerm` is a function that takes an `Int` parameter and returns an `Int` parameter (`(Int) -> Int`).

You forgot to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. A few edits. I realized I was passing the wrong value through the switch statement. Thank you for the replies.

```
  switch comparisonTerm {
        case 12:
         comparisonRate = oneYear

        case 24:
            comparisonRate =  twoYear

        case 36:
            comparisonRate =  threeYear
        case 48:
            comparisonRate = fourYear
        case 60:
            comparisonRate = fiveYear

        default:
            comparisonRate = 0

        }

        print(comparisonRate)
```

Comment: This looks an unnecessarily complicated way to just divide by 12.

Comment: There are three functions that it takes to get to the comparisonTerm. 1. Determine Maturity Date. 2 calculate the number of months from today until maturity. 3. use a switch statement to determine what comparison term to use based on the number of months to maturity. The final step, select rate based on comparison term.

Comment: Oh I thought you were assigning to `comparisonTerm`, not rate. By the way, the static analyzer can prove that `comparisonRate` is assigned to in every `case` of the `switch` statement, so you don't need to provide an initial value. You can make `comparisonRate` a `let` constant, and remove the initial assignment of `0`.